# Crystal Report SUM function with CASE

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have the following column values in my crystal report:

```
|Code |Unit |
|A    |2    |
|B    |3    |
|C    |2    |
|D    |3    |
|E    |1    |
|F    |1    |
|G    |4    |
|H    |(3)  |
```

I want to summarize the Unit except the Units which has Code H,J,K, and L.
The Codes: H,J,K, and L contains units which has parenthesis.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: how do you enclose value in parenthesis. Crystal reports are working with db so I would need detailed description of wath you want to do.

Comment: the values enclosed in parenthesis is exactly the same as in the database.

Comment: Did u format the Negative values to be displayed in parenthesis ?? And do u want to exclude those from summary??

Comment: whet is special with those value. How com that it is enclosed, that is what I am asking. If you have 8 values in db column, you have to have some if statement to enclose just one value in crystal reports.

Comment: @HariharanAnbazhagan, I didn't format them. Values with parenthesis are exactly what they are from the database. And yes, I want to exclude values with parenthesis from the summary.

Comment: @elrado, There are no if statements in the crystal report formula, as in no formula at all, values with parenthesis are the exact value that can be found in the database.

Comment: than you have string  or varchar column in database, because (3) in not numeric format.

Comment: @elrado yes, the column type is varchar, I tried summarizing the value using the isnumeric formula, but as my question suggests, I want to exclude values that has a parenthesis. I have edited my question for additional details.

Comment: @paynet look at my answer, u can write formula in Use a Formula under  evaluate field to skip the values or rows which u want to exclude... As you asked u can skip Grades which includes H,J,K, and L by using formula in Use a Formula.

Comment: @HariharanAnbazhagan, yes, I am working on it, I'll be back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude any row or value from summary, it can be done by writing your case inside ***Use a formula*** field under ***Evaluate*** in ***Running Total Field*** 
Refer the following Image...
[image: Summary]
The rows or fields which doesn't satisfy the condition will be skipped from Evaluation of summary.
Try this and get back with results !!

Comment: you no need to mention `if` or `then` there... just mention the condition `instr(totext({dtTerm_Grade.Unit}),"(")<>0` and try

Comment: `{alldata.NewPrice}<6500000` this is the sample formula i used. If Newprice is less than 6500000 then this field will be added in summary, if not it wont be added.

Comment: I tried running the summary without formula, just like the image, I put Type of Summary: Sum, I noticed it is returning the number of rows instead of the sum of values in a column, any idea?

Comment: what is the field u mentioned in **Field to Summarize** ??

Comment: yes, I want to summarize the {dtTerm_Grade.Unit} field. I tried putting the summary in report footer, page footer and group footer, still, it returns the number of rows e.g. 9. In which I have 10 rows, 1 row contains (3) thus the 9 value. And sorry for the header, I overlooked it.

Comment: are u sure that u made **Type of Summary** as SUM ??

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same as the image you posted except for the Field to Summarize which is dtTerm_Grade.Unit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18777/discussion-between-paynet-and-hariharan-anbazhagan)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit only units with ‘(‘ in it just convert this filed to number
Use

```
Val ({Unit})
```

this will return 0 for non-numeric text and number for numeric create sum of these you will get what you want

If you want not to use any special then create formula field like this

```
if {fa_rep_vr_Main.CustomTitle} not in('A','B','C') then
    0
else
    val({Unit})
```

use sum of this

If you want sum of NewPriceAD then use it in mentained field