# SUM with specific condition in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Basicalyy i want to sum data by certain condition.These are example of my data :

`Group 1 - Value:
    10,
    20,
    30,
Group 2-Value:
    10,
    20,
    30,
Group 3-Value:
    10,
    20,
    30,`

I want to sum group 1 and group 3 only.How can do it,like in sql we can write `select sum(group) from table1 where group <>'Group 2'`.How can we do that using formula.Or there's other way to do it.

Comment: These Groups are Crystal Reports Group or its a kinda field in Database ??

Comment: its a field in database.

Comment: [Refer this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134230/crystal-report-sum-function-with-case/13134461#13134461). This may help you, try and get back with results.

Comment: fUHH...it works but it seem that for one database field..u can use the running total one time only.Example if iw want to sum group 1 and group 2 in first running total.Then group 2 and group 3 in second running total.The second result is the same as the first one.

Comment: If you ignore the group 3 in formula for 1st running total, then you need to ignore the group 1 for 2nd running total, make sure that u have done this !

Comment: can you show the formula that you used inside Evaluate formula field ??

Comment: The first one i use this : `{Command.sub_group_name}<>"DEPRECIATION" `

Comment: i have 4 type of grup "DEPRECIATION","oTHERS","SUPERVISION" and "LABOUR"...The second one i just use sum without any formula.

Comment: so you got the 1st summary right?? Tell me where u are facing problem... and dont tell these as groups, these are different types of values for a field !

Comment: Yes.I got the first summary.But i didnt get the second one.The result is the same as the first one.

Comment: are u sure that u made "Evaluate" as For each record in 2nd Summary ??