# Crystal Reports Formula fields SUM only positive values using WHERE

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Within my crystal report details section i have several values from the field `amount`, i added a simple formula field to my group header to calculate the `SUM({Amount})` Which works however i only want it to `SUM` the positive values.

There is always a negative version of the positive.

Data

```
10
30
60
-10
-30
-60
```

Current Output with `SUM({Amount})`

```
0
```

Desired Output

```
100
```

Something like but in crystal variant

```
SUM({Amount}) FROM mytable WHERE {Amount} > 0
```

Comment: Looks like a case statement might work  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134230/crystal-report-sum-function-with-case  Perhaps soemthing like `Sum(case when {amount}>0 then {amount} else 0 end)` or http://forums.asp.net/t/1598073.aspx?Conditional+Sum+in+Crystal+Reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was create a new parameter called `ABSAmount` :

```
ABS({AMOUNT})
```

Then another

```
SUM({@ABSamount})/2
```

This gave me the required output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two formula to fulfill ur requrement

1.@Positive_Number

if{Table.amount} > 0 then {Table.amount} else  0

2.@Sum_of_PositiveNumber

Sum ({@positive_Number})

thanks
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be a running total that sums the {Table.amount} and evaluates on a formula.  `{Table.amount} > 0`
reset on group if your report is grouped